# I have some questions about font colors in HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to control the font color using only CSS.
My HTML source is below.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8 />
        <title>JS Bin</title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple </span>pie</span>.
        </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

I want to change "I love apple" to the blue font.

`.tag1{color : blue;}`

or

I want to change "apple pie" to the red font.

`.tag2{color : red;}`

However, only the part of "apple pie" was changed into the red font with tag2.

How do I fix it?

Comment: `<span class="tag1">I love</span> <span class="tag2">apple pie</span>.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understood you tried to match tags like this:

```
   v________________________________________________v
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple</span> pie</span>.
                            ^___________________________________^
```

This is not valid in HTML - all child tags need to be contained in parent element's scope.
(That is, this would not work either: `<div><span> </div> </span>`)

If you want to affect "I love apple" with one class and "apple pie" with another, you need to use more tags:

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple</span></span><span class="tag2"> pie</span>.
```

Or with some indentation:

```
<span class="tag1">
    I love 
    <span class="tag2">
        apple
    </span>
</span>
<span class="tag2">
 pie
</span>.
```

Comment: In fact, I want to automatically make HTML like this.
Input: key words, Html
Output: edited Html source

Answer (score 4):

Your code needs modifications.

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">appe</span> pie</span>
```

Your child `<span>` should have ended just before the parent `<span>`

Here is the solution.

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple pie</span></span>
```

Here is the **[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jHpUQ/)**

Answer (score 3):

you have to make the following change

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple pie</span></span>
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS can (with a few very minor exceptions) only select *elements*

You cannot select individual text nodes.

Move the end tag that matches `<span class="tag2">` so the element contains all the text you want to change the colour of.

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple pie</span></span>.
```

Answer (score 2):

Rearrange the `<span>` tags.

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple pie</span></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make below changes :

```
<span class="tag1">I love <span class="tag2">apple pie</span></span>
```